# How to assign a radiogroup line to a Editbox.text

Tags: delphi, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to use the lines or text next to the radiogroup's radiobuttons to be assigned to the text of a editbox or any other type of output please :) I am using Delphi 2010

Comment: What's your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Insert it to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.Items) property contains the radio button captions, and the [`ItemIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.ItemIndex) property contains the index of the radio button that is currently selected.  For example:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := RadioGroup1.Items[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex];
end;
```